# How to import default template design script in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i am a React newbie here
i am working on my first react project and i am using an bootstrap 5 template.
is it possible to import the ui scripts of this template in my react ?
they seem not to work because of the react lifecycle and DOM i think.
Sidebar toggle, charts, drop down and some other things doesnt work

```
// js
import "../assets/vendor/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js"
import "../assets/vendor/chart.js/chart.umd.js"
import "../assets/vendor/echarts/echarts.min.js"
import "../assets/vendor/quill/quill.min.js"
import "../assets/vendor/simple-datatables/simple-datatables.js"
import "../assets/vendor/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
import "../assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"
import "../assets/js/main.js"
```

i imported the css styles this way and they worked fine but the script doesnt work
how to solve this ?

thanks in advance.

i expect the script to work as it was in the template
such as the sidebar toogle, charts, drop down and some other things to work